# Abstract factory: ways of realization

Tags: oop, design-patterns, abstract-factory

I'm learning design patterns now and reading different resources for every pattern. I have a question about pattern Abstract Factory. I read about two ways of realization this. I'll write using this factories, without realization. For example, I took making different doors.

**First way**. We have common class for Door Factory, which consists different methods for making different types of doors (which returns appropriate class of door):

```
$doorFactory = new DoorFactory();
$door1 = $doorFactory->createWoodDoor();

$doorFactory = new DoorFactory();
$door2 = $doorFactory->createSteelDoor();
```

**Second way**. We have parent class DoorFactory and extends classes for WoodDoorFactory and SteelDoorFactory. This classes realises same method createDoor (and return appropriate class of Door)

```
$woodDoorFactory = new WoodDoorFactory();
$door1 = $woodDoorFactory->createDoor();

$steelDoorFactory = new SteelDoorFactory();
$door2 = $steelDoorFactory->createDoor();
```

How you think, which way more optimal and canonical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please imagine the situation when your factory is passed around, and what client code need to ask the factory is just creating a door (not care about wood and steel), you will see why the 2nd way is better. Let's say we have a class `Client` with method `foo` which uses the factory (I'm using Java but it should be easy to understand):

```
class Client {
    private DoorFactory factory;
    public Client(DoorFactory factory) { this.factory = factory; }
    public void foo() {
        Door door = factory.createDoor();
    }
}
```

Now you can pass a `WoodDoorFactory` or a `SteelDoorFactory` or `WhateverDoorFactory` to the constructor of `Client`.

Moreover, not to mention that your 1st way may be a violation of [The Single Responsibility Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) since the `DoorFactory` class knows many things which are probably unrelated. Indeed, it knows how to create a wood door which requires `Wood APIs` (just example), it knows how to create a steel door which requires `Steel APIs`. This clearly reduces the opportunity of reusing the `DoorFactory` class in another environment which does not want to depend on `Wood APIs` or `Steel APIs`. This problem does not happen with your 2nd way.

Answer (score 0):

As with the other answers, I also generally prefer the second method in practice. I've found it to be a more flexible and useful approach for Dependency Injection.

That said, I do think there are cases where the first approach works just as well if not better - they just aren't as common. An example that comes to mind is an XML Document Object Model. If you have ever used Microsoft's c++ XML DOM Document API then you will be familiar with this approach (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760218(v%3dvs.85))

In this case, there are a limited number of well-defined elements that can go into an XML document. There isn't a need to be able to dynamically extend the types of elements that can go into an XML document either - this is all predetermined by some standards committee. Therefore, the first factory approach works here, because you can predetermine all the different types of things you need to be able to create from the get-go.

The other advantage, in this case, is that by making the XML Document class the factory for all of the elements contained there-in, the XML Document has complete control over the life-time of those internal objects. NOTE: They disallow using the same sub-elements in multiple XML Document instances. If you wanted to use a node from one XML Document and place it in another XML Document, you would be required to go through the second XML Document to produce a new node element as well as a copy of any and all sub-elements.

A notable difference in this case from the example in the OP is that rather than the Factory Method being used to provide multiple ways of creating the same type of thing, here the Factory knows how to create a bunch of highly related (and connected) object types.